# Julia - PlotlyJS plotting works only in REPL

Tags: julia, plotly

I'm learning PlotlyJS.jl package and I've noticed that the window with my function plotted appears only if I use REPL - when I launch my program with `julia test.jl` command, the window with the graph doesn't show up. What is the reason of this behaviour? Is there anything I can do to make the window appear "outside" of the REPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ChrisRackauckas' answer in [a thread of the Julia forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-choose-a-plotting-package/1134/25):

> (...) Let me explain what's happening with
>   a script. In Julia, the plotting happens because the plot() command
>   returns a plot object. However, there is a difference between running
>   a command in a script, and running a command in the REPL. In the REPL:
>
> a = 2
>
> automatically returns, while
>
> a = 2;
>
> does not (like MATLAB). However, that would make you have to put ;
>   everywhere in a script, and so
>
> a = 2
>
> does now return a in a script. However, this means that plot(...)
>   doesn't actually return anything to show in a script.

This explains why the plot window appears when you run the `plot()` function from the REPL but not from a script. The default behavior for scripts is to display nothing, including plots. In order to make the plot window appear when running a script, you have to enclose the `plot()` command inside the `display()` function, like this:

```
x = 0:10
display(plot(x, x.^2))
```